# remote ssh command issue

Tags: ssh, remotecommand

Team,

I am facing some difficulties running commands on a remote machine. I am unable to understand why ssh is trying to think that the command I pass is a host.

```
ssh -tt -i /root/.ssh/teamuser.pem teamuser@myserver 'cd ~/bin && ./ssh-out.sh'

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |
| personnel.                                                      |
|                                                                 |
| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |
| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |
| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |
|                                                                 |
| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

ssh: Could not resolve hostname cd: No address associated with hostname
Connection to myserver closed.
```

It works absolutely fine if I don't pass a command. It simply logs me in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Man ssh` says:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.

The thing is that `cd` is a bash built-in (run `type cd` in your terminal). So, ssh tries to run `cd` as a shell, but can not find it in `PATH`.

You should invoke ssh something like this:

```
 ssh user@host  -t 'bash -l -c "cd ~/bin && ./ssh-out.sh"'
```